# Iterate lists/content in block template

Tags: theming

How would I be able to supersede the hierarchical dependencies in Drupal 8's twig engine to be able to loop within the i.e Lists/Views which is assigned to a block.
So we would have a block--views-block--[machine-name]-1.html.twig template we require to have the `{{ content }}` variable, which then recursively buries itself down to field templates. It is completely killing me that one would need so many levels to produce on block of content.

I would like to iterate within the top custom block template the list.

Attempted

```
{% for key, value in _context  %}
    <li>{{ key }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

To evaluate what is available to iterate down into the object but with no luck. I did though find a nice overriding object structure to reach the field attributes but that was within the field level

```
item.content['#item'].entity.uri.value
```

Comment: I get lost, what you want accomplish? Hints: Install devel module, there is a nice debug function called `kint` is a **lot** better than iterate over `_context`. And no less important, if you spend too much energy in something, is because you looking in 'wrong face' of the problem.